# Does the Higgs field also bend in gravitational space-time fields?

Tags: particle-physics, gravity, higgs

I hope I'm formulating this correctly: if the Higgs field is responsible for generating particle mass by interaction, does it bend in/around the gravitational space-time of amassed particles "given" gravity by the Higgs field? If so, does this bending of the field change its "mass-giving" interaction properties? I'm not thinking about black holes per se, since they are a singularity, but for example the gravitational bend in space-time caused by stars.

Thank you for taking the time to read or answer this question.

Comment: If I'm following your question correctly, you're asking if the gravitational field effects the Higgs field.   My first instinct is to say no because there's no evidence of a change in rest mass when an object moves through a gravitational field, but a rock at the top of a mountain has slightly more mass due to potential energy than an identical rock at the bottom of the mountain.   I don't think you need the Higgs field to explain that. The potential energy belongs to the gravitational field.   My hunch is no effect, but I'm not 100% sure I follow your question.

Comment: And this is probably better for Physics than Astronomy.

Comment: @userTLK, you've interpreted the question correctly, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The higgs field is responsible for giving mass to the gauge bosons of the weak interaction and also to the massive particles in the [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of particle physics.

The macroscopic masses of composite particles like protons, neutrons and nuclei are mainly the result of the invariant masses of summed four vectors of the elementary particles that compose them; it is not just the sum of the masses of the particles, because special relativity reigns at that level . The higgs field  contribution to the mass is small.The proton mass is about a GeV, the valence quarks add  up to a few MeV. It is the sea of quark and antiquarks and gluons with their four vectors that generate the measured proton mass (attempts at [modeling with lattice QCD](http://www.durr.itp.unibe.ch/talk_09_psi.pdf)).

It is at the classical level that masses can be summed and Archimedes principle applied. At that level the higgs field is not relevant.

At cosmological times , once quantization of gravity and a unified theory is found, it might be reasonable to expect variations in the effect of the higgs at symmetry breaking times with respect to the gravitational fields at that time, but after symmetry breaking the situation is stable, as far as lensing etc goes. It is the classical mechanics masses that apply